# Wine not working in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wine, winetricks, kindle

I updated to Ubuntu 12.04 by doing a clean install from a CD. I installed Wine, Q4wine, WineTricks, PlayOnLinux all from the Software Center.

After installing Kindle For PC(I ran it in 11.10 as well) Wine doesn't open it. Then I tried to install a game (Eastside Hockey Manager 2007) that I have had Installed on all my previous versions of Ubuntu, again Wine returned an error saying that the installer GUI would not load.

So far I'm lost as to why this is happening. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Adding the error to the question would help.

Comment: Also the version of Wine you are currently running and the last known version of Wine those programs ran under (Some programs run better under certain versions of Wine)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start Ubuntu on a previous Kernel version and see if you can run it then. I know its more like a workaround than a solution but it may help until someone can really find what the problem is.